# Is there a need to provide a std::mutex for std::async?

Tags: c++, multithreading, protected, stdasync, stdmutex

As stuff I mentioned above, Should I prodive a ***std::mutex*** for ***std::async*** in the following section? :

```
#include <vector>
#include <future>
#include <mutex>
#include <ranges>

int main()
{
    [[maybe_unused]] result=::std::async([&]
    {
        ::std::mutex s{};

        ::std::vector<int> f{};

        ::std::ranges::for_each(::std::views::iota(1) | ::std::views::take(10) | ::std::views::filter([&](const auto& iter) { return 0 == 2 % iter; }), [&](const auto& iter)
            {
                {
                    std::unique_lock guard{ s };
                    
                    f.push_back(iter);
                }
            });
    });

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone give a anwser to this problem in details? thanks!

Comment: [`std::ranges::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/for_each) apparently does not allow to provide an execution policy (in contrast to `std::for_each`), so we need to assume that elements are processed strictly in order. Then ask yourself a question: Which other thread should now access the vector – local to the lambda(!) – concurrently?

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks for your anwser! Yeah, It is apparent that there is no any thread will give access to the ::std::vector.  Maybe it just is paranoid to me.^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Aconcagua's answered above, there is no need for giving a ::std::mutex for vector.Owing to ranges was strictly executed in order.
Thanks Aconcagua for your interpretation.